# Passing Certificate to Svcutil to generate proxy for OSB Service

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, svcutil.exe, osb

We are wanting to implement Two-Way SSL security from WCF to OSB Services. We have successfully deployed the certificates so that when you browse to the service with IE you get the appropriate prompt for certificate and then it takes you immediately to the WSDL.

But, when you attempt to generate a proxy using svcutil as defined in steps 8 and 9 in this MSDN article.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949005.aspx

I get the error:

> A reply message was received for
>   operation 'Get' with    action
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer/Get'.
>   However, your client code  requires 
>   action
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer/GetResponse'.

The OSB services are set to use Soap 1.2 and the svcutil.exe.config we use is identicle to the article except for the findValue and x509FindType. Instead we used the FindByThumbprint pointing to the "My" store name and "CurrentUser" store location. The cert is there and is the same cert we select from the IE prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can save WSDL from IE on your computer and generate proxies from wsdl

Comment: The problem is with WSDL and saving files from within IE will not help.